# I want to use figures as [item] in latex

Tags: latex, tex

In latex, I can use `itemize` and `\item` as follows.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item ...
\end{itemize}
```

I also can write as follows.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[(any strings)] ...
\end{itemize}
```

However I can't write as follows.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\includegraphics{imagename}] ...
\end{itemize}
```

I want to use figures as `\item` of `itemize` in latex.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution is to switch from

```latex
\item[\includegraphics{imagename}] ...
```

to

```latex
\item \includegraphics{imagename} ...
```

The following code, for example, should compile smoothly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \includegraphics{test.jpg} some text
\item \includegraphics{test.jpg} some other
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

(make sure you have a test image file test.jpg in the same folder of your .tex file before compiling).

Other thing is to use `\item[...]` to change the item mark:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$] \includegraphics{test.jpg} some text
\item[$\diamond$] \includegraphics{test.jpg} some other
\end{itemize}
```

Finally, if you have a small/icon size image in your folder (one, test.jpg, or more), you can try this variation:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
\item[] \includegraphics{test.jpg} some text
\item[] \includegraphics{test.jpg} some other
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: What I want was your final answer! I wanted to use a small size image, but I did't know how to display only the image. I could do that following your answer! Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

The more robust way of doing this is to enclose the `\includegraphics` within braces. This way, you can also set optional parameters if you need to.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[{\includegraphics{imagename}}]
\item[{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{imagename}}]
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Matt solution solved your problem, I believe that it is not exactly what you was looking for. From what I understand you want to use your own images instead of default dots of \item in \itemize. Best solution 3 leads to "space_aka_different_dot image text", so your image won't be exactly in dot place - emptiness will. You should try instead:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\includegraphics{test.jpg}$] text
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: why do you place the image in math mode?

Comment: It didn't work without it (as question owner suggested) and inline math mode solved this just good enough for me (I am not experienced enough to give detailed explanation)

Comment: Really? This means `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\includegraphics{example-image}] text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}` does not work for you?

Comment: Your example works for me, don't know what makes this not working either for my project or for project of question owner. I guess don't use math mode if not needed, but if for some reason it doesnt work there is little harm in trying math mode.